# Opengl es2 code from xcode to visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl-es, visual-studio-2015

I'm an iOS developer and not so familiar with visual studio.

I try to move my code from mac to windows, using visual studio 2015 but I get lots of compile error.

So first, my question is how should I add openGL es2 support to a visual studio project, and second, I also need support for OES functions (that are defined on mac), like:

- glDeleteVertexArraysOES
- glBindVertexArrayOES
- glGenVertexArraysOES

**Update 1:**

I've added OpenGL ES2 files from khronos site:

```
<GLES2/gl2.h> 
<GLES2/gl2ext.h> 
<GLES2/gl2platform.h>
<KHR/khrplatform.h>
```

Is this enough? Am I forgetting a file?
**Update 2:**
I added this line

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
```

Just before the above includes.
Now I have a link error (instead of a compile error) when using glBindVertexArray:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glBindVertexArray@4 referenced in function _wWinMain@16
```

Comment: Add the OpenGL folder in your include/library include path, there lots of tutorials on the internet (and maybe even SO) to do that :)

Comment: First check that your intended platform supports openGL es2, this is a mobile platform and I don't think any Windows graphics drivers have built-in support for it.  AMD has a separate download that can add support.

Comment: I've added a description of the OpneGL files I've added to the project

Comment: What libraries did you add? What platform are the for? Where did you get them from? Note: OpenGL ES is not the same as OpenGL.

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2015. The OpenGL files are from https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/#headers32